# Edit text in PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, preview

I tried multiple times to find easy PDF editor for Mac. I am looking for an application which can simply allow me to change some words in the PDF (Preview cannot do it).

Please, pay attention that PDF editing and adding to PDF file some notes and shapes are not the same things. Preview cannot actually edit the content of the PDF.

I've purchased FineReader for a full price, but in contrast with Win version it does not allow to edit the text at all, thus my scanned and OCRed documents have some "typos" of FineReader which I want to correct.

I look for a PDF editor with only 1 ability - simply to edit text, nothing else.

---

Please do not buy w0ndershare software - they corrupt real pdf files if you use trials.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro ?

Comment: @Rafael It's too expensive. I need a simple app for occasional use. The question is for user which had the same problem and found some acceptable solution...

Comment: In general PDF is an output format generated from other sources and to chnage you edit the other sources

Answer (score 2):

The industry standard for this purpose is called …

Adobe Acrobat DC Professional

Yes, it can a lot more, but so far, I have not found any other tool which is as reliable.

Answer (score 1):

After a day long searching I think I found the best solution I could -

Master PDF Editor

Its trial version does add watermarks, but in contrast with w0ndershare and iskys0ft (I think these companies are the same - very aggressive and unhonest), the watermarks are at the top and bottom of the page and not obscuring the main page.

I bought the full version and I think it is very good for direct and actual TEXT editing.

https://code-industry.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use PDFpenPro from Smile Software, which I got at a discount as part of a bundle, because I couldn't find quality free software to do the job.

(Having built apps that interact with PDF files before, it's not easy and I wouldn't expect anybody to build software to do it for free.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. your variant is 2.5 more expensive than what I bought though...

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice is an Open Source program that works quite well for editing PDFs, and there does appear to be a Mac compatible version.